# A question on CHOLMOD: long int vs int, still failing after change to long int

Tags: linear-solver, matrix-factorization

Changing `cholmod_*` to `cholmod_l_*` results in the following error:

> *sparse:error: integer and real must match the routines*

What does this error message mean?

This message shows after

```
cholmod_l_start(&c); 
cholmod_l_print_sparse(A,"A",&c)
```

and then the following steps

```
L = cholmod_l_analyze(A,&c); 
cholmod_l_factorzie(A,L,&c); 
x=cholmod_l_solve(L,&c);
```

cannot be executed.

Motivation: the size of my matrix is large, so using `cholmod_*` will result in an error: "*problem too large*"

Comment: In order to support matrices with very large numbers of elements, it's necessary to "long int" integers rather than "int" integers for subscripting into the array.  The cholmod_l routines require you to use "long int" integers.

Comment: @Brian Borchers. OK, but if I change "A->itype = 2, A->dtype = 0", and then "cholmod_l_print_sparse(A,'x',&c)",it won't print anything unless I remove "A->itype=2,A->dtype=0",strange. How to change the itype,dtype in order to use cholmold_l?

Comment: I'm not enough of an expert on cholmod to answer this question- just trying to explain the error message.  I hope that someone else has more experience with cholmod and can answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to come with 100% explanation without seeing the source code, but I predict that one of the following things had happened:

- most likely, your matrix `A` was **not initially created with a support for `long int` indexes** and increased size limitations. And simple manual changing `A->itype` will not solve this problem because effectively the matrix has to be reconstructed to support `long int` indexes. At least, I am not aware of CHOLMOD routine that converts one to another.
- You are continuing to use `int` indexes instead of `long int` ones somewhere during the process. CHOLMOD has an internal type `SuiteSparse_long` and that is the one that you should be using.

CHOLMOD actually has two very good examples:

- *demo/cholmod_demo.c*
- *demo/cholmod_l_demo.c*

that perform exactly the same set of actions on "standard" and "large" matrices.